# NameError uninitialized constant CouponsController::Coupon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, nameerror

After you signup I will get a Name Error saying

```
def index
 @coupons = Coupon.all
end
```

I think it's the "Coupon.all" portion. [image]

Comment: Do you have `Coupon` model?

Comment: yep. https://github.com/BBaughn1/Coupon-Site/tree/master/app/models right here, and the full project: https://github.com/BBaughn1/Coupon-Site

Comment: Change the filename `coupons.rb` to `coupon.rb`

Comment: that works. Now I have an active record error, "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Coupons#index" and it's saying that towards "<% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>"

Comment: Change the code in `coupon.rb` as model. `Class Coupon < AvtiveRecord::Base end`

Comment: it was already like that. class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base end
https://github.com/BBaughn1/Coupon-Site/blob/master/app/models/coupon.rb

Comment: Do you have any data in the coupons table?

Comment: it's been made yesterday, so no one has used it yet. I am working out the kinks. Login doesn't work, and signup has some problems.

Comment: So,that means no data in the coupons table?

Comment: not yet. trying to load up this: https://github.com/BBaughn1/Coupon-Site/blob/master/app/views/coupons/index.html.erb

Comment: Hmm. You need to put the iteration part in a `<% if @coupons.present? %>` `<% end %>`

Comment: so instead of <% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>, do <% if @coupons.present? %> ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any data in `coupons` table, `@coupons` returns ***nil***. You need add a condition in the view.

```
<% unless @coupons.blank? %>
  <% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
   ---rest of the code---
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Coupons#index"
now it says that "if @coupons.present?" is invalid

Comment: @BrendonBaughn Sorry. Updated :)

Comment: @BrendonBaughn Try restarting the server

Comment: didn't work. I got this in my terminal: ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: coupons: SELECT "coupons".* FROM "coupons"):

Comment: @BrendonBaughn You should have coupons table in your ***DB***

Comment: @BrendonBaughn I meant the databse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85335/discussion-between-brendon-baughn-and-pavan).